# Compare HDD and SSD performance

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ssd

I have just ordered my first SSD, and I want to run some tests on my current HDD now, and then run the same tests again once I get my SSD up and running in a couple of days, so I can see in detail how faster the new SSD is.

Can you recommend a (or a number of) good hard drive benchmarking tools for this sort of task?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good one for HDDs is [HDTUNE](http://www.hdtune.com).

Overclockers seem to like [AS SSD](http://alex-is.de/PHP/fusion/downloads.php?download_id=9).

I've read mixed reviews on benchmarking SSDs, but a test or two shouldn't kill it.

Probably the best upgrade you can make to any modern system.

Comment: Thanks, got a 3 year warranty with it, so as you say a test or two shouldn't do too much damage.